# SwiftUI modal doesn't show

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My code:

```
 @State var newMoodForModal: Int? = nil


Text("Tap to Add Note").onTapGesture {
                        print("tapped")
                        newMoodForModal = moodEntries.lastIndex(of: moodEntries.last!) ?? 0
                        print(newMoodForModal)
                    }.sheet(item: $newMoodForModal) { item in
                        MoodEntryModalView(entry: moodEntries[item], saveNote: {
                            do {
                                try context.save()
                            } catch {
                                print(error)
                            }
                        }, deleteMood: {
                            context.delete(moodEntries[item])
                            do {
                                try context.save()
                            } catch {
                                print(error)
                            }
                        })
                    }
```

When I tap, I get "tapped" output and correct `newMoodForModal` number in console but for some reason the modal doesn't show.

I have got similar code with MoodEntryModalView modal using another @State variable in another place (I tried deleting it but it didn't help) which works fine so it looks strange for me.

Comment: Why do you use `Int` as the `item` parameter instead of some `Mood` object? It might be better to use `Mood` (and conform it to Identifiable). Also make sure there is no other sheet in this view which will override your Mood sheet.

Comment: It turned out I had another modal I forgot about which didn't let this one appear. Int works fine for me.